# multiple selection from listbox in c#

Tags: asp.net, listbox, multipleselection

I was wondering how do i allow user to make only make 3 selection from a list box.I am looking at this code,i think there is some logic error to this but i cant see what went wrong as im new to this can someone please guide me or share some article with me so that i can work on this,thank you:)

my code

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex <= 4)
     errorProvider1.SetError(listBox1, "Please pick 1.");
else
     errorProvider1.SetError(listBox1, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [ASP.NET-CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this:

Providing a client-validation function:

```
function validateSelectionCount(sender, args){
    var listbox = document.getElementById('ListBox1');
    args.IsValid = validateListBoxSelectionCount(listbox, 3, 3);
} 

function validateListBoxSelectionCount(listbox, minSelected, maxSelected){
    var selected=0;
    if(listbox != null){
        for (var i=0; i<listbox.length; i++){
            if(listbox.options[i].selected){
               selected++; 
               if(selected>maxSelected)break;
            }
        }
    }
   return (selected >= minSelected && selected <= maxSelected);
}
```

providing a server-validate function:

```
Protected Sub validateSelectionCount(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    Dim count As Int32 = 0
    Dim maxCount As Int32 = 3
    Dim minCount As Int32 = 3
    Dim lb As ListBox = DirectCast(Me.FindControl(DirectCast(source, CustomValidator).ControlToValidate), ListBox)
    For Each item As ListItem In lb.Items
        If item.Selected Then count += 1
        If count > maxCount Then Exit For
    Next
    args.IsValid = (count >= minCount AndAlso count <= maxCount)
End Sub
```

and the aspx part:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE" runat="server" CssClass="content" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV_SelectionCount" runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction="validateSelectionCount" OnServerValidate="validateSelectionCount" ControlToValidate="ListBox1" Display="None" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Select 3 items" Style="visibility: hidden" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: im currently doing it on a web form i can implemant this too? c#

Answer (score 2):

Saurabh is right, Set you Listbox property of SelectionMode to Multiple. This will allow you to make multiple selections from your listbox.

Comment: set it to mutiplesimple or multiple exended

Comment: I think you shouldn't bother about simple and extended. Your requirement will be fulfilled after setting its property to `SelectionMode = Multiple`

Comment: so meaning it dosent matter which ever i set it to? and how do i write to enable user to select only 3,and when they select the 4th the error provider will appear

Comment: you didn't mention this in your question. Okay then you have to write custom validator as described by Tim Schmelter. It will be written in c# and in .cs file.